# .Net Calling NetworkStream.Read() twice caused about 100ms overhead, what's the cause?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am writing a simple Tcp communication programs using TcpListener and TcpClient , .Net 4.7.1

I designed my own protocol to be:
For each "data unit", the first 4 bytes is an int, indicating the length of data body. Once a complete "data unit" is received, the data body (as a byte[]) is passed to upper level.

My read and write functions are:

```
    public static byte[] ReadBytes(Stream SocketStream)
    {
        int numBytesToRead = 4, numBytesRead = 0, n;

        byte[] Length = new byte[4];
        do
        {
            n = SocketStream.Read(Length, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        } while (numBytesToRead > 0 && n != 0);

        if (n == 0) return null; //network error

        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(Length);

        numBytesToRead = BitConverter.ToInt32(Length, 0); //get the data body length
        numBytesRead = 0;

        byte[] Data = new byte[numBytesToRead];
        do
        {
            n = SocketStream.Read(Data, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        } while (numBytesToRead > 0 && n != 0);

        if (n == 0) return null; //network error

        return Data;
    }

    public static void SendBytes(Stream SocketStream, byte[] Data)
    {
        byte[] Length = BitConverter.GetBytes(Data.Length);
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(Length);
        SocketStream.Write(Length, 0, Length.Length);
        SocketStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
        SocketStream.Flush();
    }
```

And I made a simple echo program to test the RTT:

```
    private void EchoServer()
    {
        var Listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 23456);
        Listener.Start();
        var ClientSocket = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        var SW = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        var S = ClientSocket.GetStream();
        var Data = new byte[1];
        Data[0] = 0x01;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SW.Restart();
        SendBytes(S, Data); //send the PING signal
        ReadBytes(S); //this method blocks until signal received from client
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ping: " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Text = "Ping: " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        SW.Stop();
    }

    private void EchoClient()
    {
        var ClientSocket = new TcpClient();
        ClientSocket.Connect("serverIP.com", 23456);
        var S = ClientSocket.GetStream();
        var R = ReadBytes(S); //wait for PING signal from server
        SendBytes(S, R); //response immediately
    }
```

In "ReadBytes", I have to read 4 bytes from the NetworkStream first in order to know how many bytes I have to read next. So in total I have to call NetworkStream.Read twice, as shown in above codes.

The problem is: I discovered that calling it twice resulted in around 110ms RTT. While calling it once(regardless of data completeness) is only around 2~10ms(put a "return Length;" immediately after the first do-while loop, or comment out the first do-while loop and hard-code the data length, or read as much as it can in one call to "Read").

If I go for the "read as much as it can in one call" method, it may result in "over-read" of data and I have to write more lines to handle the over-read data to assemble next "data unit" correctly.

Anyone knows what's the cause of the almost 50 times overhead?

As I read from Micrisoft

> Microsoft improved the performance of all streams in the .NET Framework by including a built-in buffer.

so even if I call .Read twice, it's only reading from memory, am I correct?

(if you want to test the codes, please do it on a real server and connect from your home PC maybe, do it in localhost always returns 0ms)

Comment: Write-write-read -- might this be a Nagle issue?

Comment: I tried to combine the byte array first and use a single Stream.Write/Stream.Flush and it makes no different.

Comment: Some questions. Which line is the issue referring to? When you say "read" - do you really mean "consume" - as in, once the bytes are read from the stream, they come off the stream? It sounds to me that is what you are doing here.

Comment: and thanks for the reminder, I will try google Nagle's algorithm in .Net's NetworkStream

Comment: @theMayer the 2 do-while loops in "ReadBytes", though it is a loop, it only executed once in my experiment, so 2 do-while loops called SocketStream.Read twice in total.

Comment: Does this code currently work correctly, other than the time delay? I would assume that offset should always be zero, as it should be pulling from a network buffer (not memory). I think anytime this loop executes more than once, you'll have a bug.

Comment: @theMayer The code worked correctly except the delay. The offset should NOT always be zero depending on how you read the buffer and the programming logic. Most of the time the loop only runs once because most of the time it can read enough data already in one call. The reason I said it may be read from memory is Microsoft said the NetworkStream has its buffer built-in.

Comment: @theMayer you may want to look at this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2 to see why the offset is NOT always zero

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Jeroen Mostert's comment reminder. I added:

```
                ClientSocket.NoDelay = true;
                ClientSocket.Client.NoDelay = true;
```

to both the client and server side and the annoying delay is gone, the RTT is back to expected.

[TcpClient.NoDelay Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Further tests showed that both sides(client and server) contributed around 50ms delay without modifying "NoDelay" option, so in total around 100ms RTT "overhead".